# How does Immutable.js transform a JS object to Immutable?

Tags: redux, immutable.js

How to convert a javascript object to immutable object?

for example：
Immutable.Map({name: 'tom'})

Comment: Principle of internal operation

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS